# React Router - How can I reuse my layout for the errorElement in the root route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router v6 and following are my routes:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <HomePage />,
      },
      {
        path: '/sign-up',
        element: <SignUpPage />,
      },
      {
        path: '/log-in',
        element: <LogInPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement,
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

The `App` component contains my app's layout and outputs the route elements using the `Outlet` component. But now if there's an error that bubbles up to the root route, then the `ErrorPage` gets displayed as expected, but it doesn't make use of the layout from `App`... So, how can I reuse my layout from `App` when the error page gets displayed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When there's an error it is kind of an either/or kind of scenario. Either the conditions are fine, and the `App` component is rendered ***or*** there's an error condition, and the `ErrorPage` component is rendered.

What you could do is abstract the layout portion of the `App` component into a layout component on its own that can render either a passed `children` prop ***or*** the `Outlet` component for the nested route, and render it in `App` and also wrap the `ErrorPage` component.

Example:

```
const AppLayout = ({ children }) => (
  ...
  {children ?? <Outlet />}
  ...
);
```

```
const App = () => (
  ...
  <AppLayout />
  ...
);
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />, // <-- uses Outlet
    errorElement: (
      <AppLayout>     // <-- uses children
        <ErrorPage />
      </AppLayout>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <HomePage />
      },
      {
        path: "/sign-up",
        element: <SignUpPage />
      },
      {
        path: "/log-in",
        element: <LogInPage />
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

[image: Edit react-router-how-can-i-reuse-my-layout-for-the-errorelement-in-the-root-route]

Comment: But in this case `<AppLayout />` component will be re-created between navigation? No?

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi It *might*, depending on where `AppLayout` is in the ReactTree. React and React-Router-DOM try to keep components mounted as much as possible so the extra work of unmounting and remounting the same component is avoided. Is there a specific issue you have because of my answer here?

Comment: No issues; it was only mentioned that `<AppLayout />` may re-render, which could result in the loss of state.

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi Sure, this is basically just a bare-bones minimal implementation example. If there is any state that needs to "persist" you can always lift it higher in the ReactTree to a stable location if there is an problem with the layout remounting.